# ActionBar in Kivy does not process text in ActionButton in 'larger' application

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I have the following code in a `.kv` file for adding an `ActionBar`. When in a small sized application this works without any problems. When adding this code to a large sized application, I get the Critical Clock warning:

```
 [CRITICAL] [Clock       ] Warning, too much iteration done before the
 next frame. Check your code, or increase the Clock.max_iteration
 attribute.
```

I have changed the `kivy_clock` settings but there was no setting that resolved the problem.

When I put the text: attribute of the `ActionButton` in comments or replace it with an icon, the `ActionBar` is shown correctly without any warnings.

What could be the issue here? I am pretty desperate.

```
ActionBar:
    font_size: 8
    height: 45
    background_image: './images/white-bg.png'
    background_color: 0.6,.6,.6,1
    ActionView:
        ActionPrevious:
            title: "NovaGuide"
            with_previous: False
            app_icon: './images/NG-Creator32.png'
        ActionOverflow:
        ActionButton:
            text: "help"
        ActionButton:
            icon: './images/ic-menu-white.png'
        ActionGroup:
            icon: './images/ic-menu-white.png'
            ActionButton:
                text: "profile"
```

Comment: I had the same problem once when I used size_hints and absolute sizes which did make sense together. I guess in your case kivy is doing the same.  Trying to calculate the size of widgets but it does not find a solution fast enouh or at all. To check that it would be helpful if you could provide more code.

Comment: Your guess is quite accurate ;-) and in my case it makes sense together. Therefore it is difficult to provide more code as this will the whole code base of the application. I don't have a problem with that in general except that I only want to provide such code base through PM. Would that be possible?

Comment: Mhm. How should this work? I won't post my email here.